# Undertow with resteasy fails

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, resteasy, undertow

How to make it work the resteasy with undertow. It serving the pages well. but it not serving the JSON request.

But while running in Eclipse it works fine. it not working while run using

> jar -cp myjar.jar my.main

Here is my error

```
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.MyClass of media type: application/json
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:205)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:208)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My pom

```
<!-- undertow to embed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
            <version>${undertow.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${undertow.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
            <version>${undertow.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-undertow</artifactId>
            <version>${org.jboss.resteasy.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

My App

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class App extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

    private Injector injector;

    public App(Injector injector) {
        this.injector = injector;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(SwaggerServlet.class);
        resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        final Set<Object> objects = new HashSet<>();

        objects.add(injector.getInstance(MyClass.class));

        return objects;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        return Collections.emptyMap();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working file after adding

```
resources.add(ResteasyJackson2Provider.class);
```

in getClasses() method.